# AceGen map result for new variable

Tags: acegen

I am using AceGen default material SED3H1DFHYH1DOgdenU1 and for this material I want to create resultant  map which will show me map for the energy but only if it is above some treshold. I am using the code bellow:

```
StrainEnergyBelovTreshold[W_] := Block[{},
 tresholod = SMSReal[0];
 lowLevel = SMSReal[0];
 SMSIf[W > tresholod];
    Fi = W;
 SMSElse[];
    Fi= lowLevel;
  SMSEndIf[]
];
```

I call this function in Tangent and residual module after the ConstitutiveEquations function which gives the value of the W. The code is compiling without errors but when I try to calculate the task I get this errors:

- LinkRead::linkep: An unexpected end of packet was received.
- Set::shape: Lists {AceFEM Private q16$24195,AceFEM Private q12$24195} and $Aborted are not the same shape.
- Intersection::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in AceFEM Private

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you supply example values for `W`?

Comment: @Bartek Could you please update your question with the part of the code ("Tangent and residual" module) where you call your function. It is easier to help you, if the question is more self-contained.   What I already see from your code is that special AceGen operators (`RightTee` and `DoubleRightTee`) are missing. You should fix this first.  Also I think it is better to make `W` NOT the argument of your function, but leave it as a global symbol (see other examples of "functions" in AceGen code).

Comment: @Jagra the value for the W is around 0.42

Comment: @Pinti the code above is imprecise in the original code I use the `DoublewRightTee` and here is code which I'm using to call function `StrainEnergyBelovTreshold[W];` thanks for suggestion I will change the function and see what happens.